# insert anchor element before every bar column ti make it tabbable

Tags: d3.js, anchor, nvd3.js, section508

I am trying to make my chart 508 compliant. Hence in order to make it possible to navigate the chart using keyboard, i want to add anchor elements before every bar column. I tried doing :

```
d3.select("svg").insert("a",".nv-bar").attr("href","");
```

but it didnt work.
Can anybody suggest a better way of doing it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-bar')
  .each(function() {
    var el = this;
    d3.select(el.parentNode)
      .insert('a', function(){return el;})
      .attr('href', '');
  });
```

The insert method will add elements to each item in the current selection, regardless of how many elements the "before" parameter matches.

My solution will add an anchor for each bar in the document, and takes advantage that the [insert](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert) method can accept a selector string or a function that returns an element to insert before. (Although, somewhat frustratingly, it does not accept a DOM node directly)

Edit: Here's a jsfiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/bgp6atzo/

Comment: I added a working jsfiddle using this example. Can you share your code that isn't working? Or did I misunderstand your question and this isn't what you wanted it to do?

Comment: jsfiddle helped in correcting my mistake. thanks :) adding anchor elements works. even though I am still not able to navigate through the chart using tab keys.